# CSV coming out as pipe-delimited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, erb

I created a Rails file outputting values separated by commas, called posts.csv.erb.

When I click on the link, it downloads as a CSV file, but the commas are now pipes. Also, Vim tries to auto-correct the commas into pipes for some reason (but I got around that, so they are actually commas). It works fine if I call the file posts.txt.erb - I see actual commas. But somehow it seems Rails or ERB wants to output pipes for a CSV file?

Comment: Never seen anything like that - can you show some code? I also strongly recommended using the ruby CSV library rather than generating the csv yourself

Comment: That's okay, it must be some plugin and I'll use CSV library.